# Statistical Significant and Biological effect?

Tags: statistical-significance, effect-size, biostatistics, reporting

I was just recently wondering how to solve this problem: I have a set of experiments which I did by myself and I analyzed the data and ran the statistical tests (Mann-whitney test). Analysing the raw data you can clearly see that there is absolutely no difference between the groups or this difference is so minimal that may not reflect any biological effect.

However, the statistical tests show a small but statistic significance. For example: I have some measurements with neurons (9 values each group) which show mean values of 25.15 group A and 25.9 group B.

In my opinion, the one who analyse the data, I believe that there would be no biological effect. If I report the result as "non significant" although it is, would this be  wrong? would there be any test to correctly reinforce my analysis?

Comment: Firstly, reporting something as not significant when your test says it is, just because your gut feeling disagrees with the test, is certainly wrong. You should report the results as you got them, although you are of course free to then qualify those with your own interpretations. To answer the rest of your question, I think we'd need to know a bit more about your data. In what way is there "clearly" no difference when you look at it? Could you plot the data so we can see what you mean? And what is it that your testing, exactly?

Comment: @Ruben vam Bergen Hi... thanks you very much! I am doing Mann-Whitney test. Here is my raw data. Group A (25,15/25,21/25,20/25,29/25,38/27,70/25,71/25,77/24,62) Group B (25,65/25,52/26,01/25,68/26,11/26,19/25,99/25,74/25,84)

Comment: Please post your summary statistics for the test. I want the test statistics and your p-value. Just copy-and-paste R output to the question.

Comment: Hi.. I don't use R I use graphpad Prism :) here it is the results from Prism
Mann Whitney test 
  P value 0,0314
  Exact or approximate P value? Exact
  P value summary *
  Significantly different? (P < 0.05) Yes
  One- or two-tailed P value? Two-tailed
  Sum of  ranks in column A,B 61,00 , 110,0
  Mann-Whitney U 16,00
 
Difference between medians 
  Median of column A 25,29
  Median of column B 25,84
  Difference: Actual -0,5500
  Difference: Hodges-Lehmann -0,4700
  96.01% CI of difference -0,8400 to -0,07000
  Exact or approximate CI? Exact

Comment: Is there any problem with reporting that there was some indication of an effect p=0.0314, but that the Hodges-Lehmann estimator indicated an effect size of -0,4700 (CI -0.8400 to -0.07000), which suggests that while there might be an effect, it is not of a biologically relevant size (if you judge it to be that way)? Statistically signficicant and relevant are two separate things that should not be confused.

Comment: @Björn,
Hi... many thanks! No there would be no problem...I just have to discuss a little bit  better. Ja, I know many people confuse statistical significance and biological relevance. In my case I really see that the difference is minimal to have such effect. Thanks!